# How far off-topic can we get in the Code Review General Chat Room?

Tags: discussion, chat

What is considered off-limits in chat?

Comment: You actually did it? lol

Comment: Does anyone get the messages sent to the @StackExchange bot?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some context as to why you ask this question?

Comment: @Hosch250, this was nearly 2 years ago, we were just getting things kicked off here on CR and we were a rather chatty bunch (*even me*), so I wanted to know if we were going too far in chat. keep in mind though that back then there was probably between 5-10 regulars far less than what we have now, so the atmosphere was more contained, in that we could discuss things more easily and we also posted a lot to Meta rather than try to discuss in chat, which is the way it should be.

Comment: @Malachi OK, I missed the date and thought it was about the recent issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [*Talk in Chat* privilege page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat):

> **When should I visit chat?**
>
> - for real time collaboration
> - to meet the fellow members of your community in a more social environment
> - for less structured, casual (**but still roughly on-topic**) conversation

As this primarily pertains to *this* specific room, yes, I'd avoid going too off-topic.  From what I've seen so far, we're still okay.  Most of the discussion is related to site maintenance, which is absolutely okay.

One thing I should point out: *the rooms can be seen by anyone*.  This is not only for moderation reasons, but also because the rooms are generally expected to help add some "side-knowledge" to the site (they are still not a substitute to main site posts).  There are also gallery chat rooms, but the only difference is that certain people can *post*, but everyone can still *view* the messages.

Beyond that, off-topic discussion is not greatly discouraged.  Small-talk shouldn't cause a problem, but I also wouldn't make that the entire focus.  It still has to be respectful, of course.  I will not hesitate to take action if things start to heat up, but I'm sure we're much too responsible to let it go that far.

I also leave you with the [Definitive rules on chat rooms with non-technical discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139362/definitive-rules-on-chat-rooms-with-non-technical-discussion).

Answer (score 6):

I think that you can go as far as you want in chat, assuming nobody there complains.
Otherwise, I don't see any harm in being off-topic there.

And if somebody complains, just move the discussion to another room.

Comment: "as far as you want", without flaming, insulting, etc...