# Chat Bot for 2nd Monitor chat room

Tags: discussion, chatbot

Following these posts

- [How far off-topic can we get in the Code Review General Chat Room?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1030/18427)
- [What are the Stack Exchange limits on chatbots?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1291/18427)
- [Chat bot feature requests](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1633/18427)

I found that there was a Bot running in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), which is Superuser's main chat room.

I [gathered the code for this chat bot **(from here)**](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot), and I want to host the bot for CR once I figure it all out and play with the code a little bit.

maybe even have a testing bot permanently set up in a chat room currently called [BlueCheese Monster's Home](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14370/bluecheese-monsters-home)

This bot has a way to kill the bot and revive the bot, and I believe that the bot also has a command for SuperUsers to ban certain people from sending commands to the bot.

There is a lot of stuff this bot can do

- Tell you the Weather
- Google
- Define (via wiki)
- etc.

This bot is built using Javascript.

Things I would like to do with the bot

- Read an RSS feed and Respond accordingly with our goals
- Meta Answers - depending on settings.
- Main Answers - depending on settings.
- Ping user upon arrival (if they are signed up and/or have a high enough tag score) with the most active (or least active) question for their highest scored tag.  *-just an idea*

---

Right now what I need for this bot is

- Name (Currently BlueCheeseMonster)
- Invocation (Currently "CR")
- Avatar

Comment: `Ping user upon arrival` Well this should not be automatic unless the person wants to be ping. This could be really noisy if it pings everyone who join.

Comment: there is already a welcome command @Marc-Andre.  I need to change it in the code though I think, it has some quirks. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15396122#15396122

Comment: I like the Welcome back though, maybe have the bot remember when they saw someone last???  make people feel welcomed and/or missed so they keep coming back.

Comment: My personal preference is no welcome at all, but this is my opinion ;).

Comment: @Marc-Andre I like that the command needs to be given for the welcome to happen. but I would like to put it up to the chat community too, because I think it would be fun to play with automation of responses and stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Tool vs Toy.

I have worked in chat rooms before where a bot was able to provide meaningful service (as well as occasional entertainment value).

If this bot is primarily a tool, and not a toy, then I can see a future where it is a valuable contributor to the chat room.

In order to qualify as "primarily tool" it has to have functionality that is useful for the community. Features that are Tool Like are:

- user stats (get/share details on users) so that you can do things like: Oh, some user just posted an interesting question...: `Bot flair username` and it will dump the statistics for that user (CR stats, network stats, etc).
- site stats : Question/Answer ratios, Questions/day, etc
- site activity: new questions, new answers, etc.
- meta activity: new questions/answers
- template comment library (templates for new question with code-link only, etc.) (perhaps integrated with the auto-comment script?)
- more ....

Things like 'norris' (chuck norris quotes), etc. are 'toys', and should not be the primary focus.

Comment: I like the Template Comment Library.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine: the bot is currently not on-topic, but could be modified to be on-topic.

Comment: @200_success that is my goal, well that and learning some javascript syntax and how everything works

Answer (score 5):

From the [Chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#about):

> ### What can we chat about?
>
> This site is an extension of The Stack Exchange Network, so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at The Stack Exchange Network — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.
>
> All chat occurs in a room; each room has a defined topic.
>
> When talking in a room, it's polite to stay roughly on topic for the room, as defined by the room owners. If you find yourself consistently veering into other topics, you should consider taking it to another room.

From your description, the bot you propose would be off-topic for any Code Review chat room. We have been somewhat lenient when it comes to letting regular members of CR discuss whatever they want in The 2nd Monitor, in order to foster a sense of community. However, a bot that regularly posts off-topic messages would not be welcome, in my judgement.

You are of course welcome to post anything you want to [Test room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10121/test-room).

Comment: I do want this bot to be on-topic in our chat room, in my eyes it isn't finished yet. I want to dig through the code and see if I can't add to what it is already.

Comment: this bot is in a Test room at the moment. should I have added the bot into the room that you mention?

Comment: Using the Test room would have been easier, but creating a temporary room for use during development is also acceptable.