# Blue Cheese Monster feature requests

Tags: discussion, chat, chatbot

Malachi and I, we broke our heads on how we can disambiguate the Blue Cheese Monster, especially in respect to the [Tool vs. Toy question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1849/37660) raised by rolfl.

So here goes:

## What features does this tool need to be useful to the community?

Please post feature requests below.

It would be nice if you could provide:

> - What does the command do?
> - Example invocation
> - Possible restrictions
> - (*for the overly enthusiastic*) implementation "blueprint" / syntax

<sub>The Current Bot that is implemented is written in JavaScript, and is being run in a Chrome browser</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ban User From Commanding Bot

Obvious usage if the user is abusing the bot.

---

### Privilege settings

keep users from creating too many commands or specifying what users can and cannot tell the bot to do.

Answer (score 5):

Especially in respect to @rolfls definitely correct and useful objections, Malachi and me just came up with a possible solution:

#### Command Types:

As mentioned int [@rolfls answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1849/37660) some commands are *Toys* and some are *Tools*. As a [feature-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to the bot, there *should* be some owner-only (read: mods) command, that sets the bot to allow or disallow calls to the toy-commands.

Every new "learned" command would start out as a [toy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toy), until an owner (read: mod, maybe community majority) promotes the command to a [tool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool). In the tool-mode, every call to a toy command will just be either ignored or shunned off.

### Command:

```
The command switches the Blue Cheese Monster from "tool" to "toy" and back
CR playtime / CR playtime over
This command may only be invoked by The Powers that Be
```

This would also require another command:

```
The command promotes another command to the "tool"-status or back
CR tool [command] / CR toy [command]
This command also may only be invoked by The Powers that Be
Alternatively it could evaluate votes (7 Votes to promote, Binding vote from TPTB)
```

### EDIT:

As there have been some misunderstandings on the purpose of this command in chat, a little clarification. This command is intended as a **"partial kill switch"**. The toy-part of the Blue Cheese Monster can horrendously be abused. Thus Malachi and me thought of this as a way to prevent abuse, but maintain the tool functionality of the bot. This is not meant to be a black/white distinction, just an additional security mechanism

Comment: This tool/toy classification is useful to determine whether the bot is a contributor, or distraction in the chat room. It does not need to have a flag on each feature determining whether that feature is a tool/toy.... it just needs to be: *'this bot, in general, is a tool that can also be a toy'*

Comment: Toys shouldn't run in The 2nd Monitor at all.  Development should be done on a development instance of the bot, running in another chat room.  As for the kill switch, moderators or the chat room owners can ban the bot's account from posting.

Comment: @200_success: Mods may be able to, but room owners **cannot** ban a particular account from posting. The only available choices are an open chat room where anybody can post, or gallery mode where only approved posters can post. The only route for non-mod users to ban a particular account is auto-banning if a sufficient number of posts are flagged.

Answer (score 5):

> `CR register-feed {key} {url}`

**Purpose**: registers specified RSS feed url with specified key/identifier, and posts whatever comes up in that feed as a chat message, hopefully with a link.

**Example**:

```
CR register-feed cr-answers http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/codereview.stackexchange/answers&body=true
```

---

> `CR unregister-feed {key}`

**Purpose**: forget about specified RSS feed url; stop posting feed items as chat messages.

**Example**:

```
CR unregister-feed cr-answers
```

---

> `CR list-feeds`

**Purpose**: displays a list of all registered RSS feed URL's and the keys they're registered under.

**Example**:

```
CR list-feeds
```

Comment: when I get the RSS stuff figured out I would love to try to implement this!

Answer (score 2):

[suggested-improvement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-improvement)

#### Current status:

On being unsummoned, the bot currently just vanishes. But the useraccount still remains.

#### Suggestion:

Have the bot give a last message, before retreating to his cave, something along the lines of :

> ByeBye I am back to my cave now.

And he should really quit the room, and not just hang around ;)